# How can i dynamically add back button to nav bar in ios [React Native]?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using Router flux library, Basically i want to show the back button on my navbar only if session exists, or else i need to hide the back button. Is it possible?

this is my scene

```
    <Scene
      component={Devices}
      hideNavBar={true}
      key='devices'
      title='Devices'
      headerTintColor="#ffffff" />
```

I have Disabled backbutton like this in my component.

```
export default class Devices extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    headerLeft: null
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it

```
//If session does not exists
Actions.refresh({key: 'devices', renderLeftButton:null});
```